# How do I run php scripts on a host's server via command line?

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-extension

I have a hosting provider with mediawiki installed, I am trying to install an extension and I have to navigate to a directory on their server and run an install.php script. How do i do this? I have filezilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually call the install script via a browser, e.g.

- http://example.com/install.php

Note: usually you have to edit the MediaWiki configuration file as well when adding extensions.

Comment: note: I am assuming you want to install a mediawiki extension, so my answer is oriented towards that target...

Answer (score 0):

Get a SSH client such as PuTTY and use it to connect to the host's SSH service. Assuming they have one. If they don't, then you won't be able to do that.